# docker: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I was trying to install tensorflow using docker. I used code provided by a book as follows:

`$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 –p 6006:6006\ cargo.caicloud.io/tensorflow/ tensorflow:0.12.0`

however, the terminal shows error messages

> docker: invalid reference format

I am not familiar with docker and I doubt this error is due to the space key around words  cargo and tensorflow, I tried many ways to rearrange space key but still could not get result. Can anyone familiar with docker solve this issue? thanks.

Comment: The backslash here `6006\\` should not be there.

Comment: You had selected the right answer

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.infoq.com/cn/articles/introduction-of-tensorflow-part02) did show a `\`, but that was because it was a multiline command.

On one line, you would need:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 –p 6006:6006 cargo.caicloud.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0
```